# Error when deploying war file on tomcat

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xsd, ubuntu-14.04

Trying to run my JSF project on Tomcat in Ubuntu but I get the following error
when I try to deploy the WAR file using the built-in manager:

FAIL - Application at context path /Server Communication could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Server Communication]]

```
Log: 

Mar 06, 2015 9:22:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Server Communication/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-el-api-8.0.18.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Server Communication/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.18.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:27 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:27 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI:
        http://java.sun.com/jsf/html
     is already defined
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core is already defined
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://mojarra.dev.java.net/mojarra_ext is already defined
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-app_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-fragment_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-common_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_7.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 06, 2015 9:22:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same set of errors when trying to deploy my project on Tomcat via Eclipse Luna. Fortunately, I'm using Maven and could create a new run configuration with `tomcat:run` as its goal. Then running the application on Tomcat works just fine. Alternatively, just run the following if you're using Maven:

`> mvn clean install tomcat:run`

[See this video for an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-Y15VPw5KA).